# Android Studio keyboard shortcuts not working

Tags: shortcut-keys, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 3 on Ubuntu 16.14 with no problems in the build and functionality. The only thing is sometime weirdly the simple keys shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.
When they stop I try to refocus on the app and windows by clicking and trying everything but it does not work, until some time of switching forth and back it works again. How can I solve this?

*Update:* After posting this I discovered the issue happens when I switch keyboard language from English to Arabic, so as long as I am on English all is fine, but this does not happen on other apps shortcuts work fine with both languages.